# Fill frame on window resize

Tags: python, tkinter

When you enter a file name in the entry filed and click the "Open" button, the content will be displayed.

I want the Entry and Text widget to completely fill Frame3 (red) and continue to do so when the application window is resized. How do I achieve this?

This is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

ALL = N+S+W+E

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid(sticky=ALL)


        def handler(event):
            print("clicked at", event.x, event.y)

        def show_entry_fields():
            #print  e1.get()
            f=open(e1.get())
            out_put=f.read()
            l1=Label(f3, text=out_put,fg="purple").grid(row=5,column=2)
            return out_put
        def call_red():
            out_put=show_entry_fields()
            Label(f3, text=out_put,fg="red").grid(row=5,column=2)
        def call_green():
            out_put=show_entry_fields()
            Label(f3, text=out_put,fg="green").grid(row=5,column=2)
        def call_blue():
            out_put=show_entry_fields()
            Label(f3, text=out_put,fg="blue").grid(row=5,column=2)
        def call_black():
            out_put=show_entry_fields()
            Label(f3, text=out_put,fg="black").grid(row=5,column=2)

        for r in range(4):
            self.rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
        self.master.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        b1=Button(self, text="Red",command=call_red).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=ALL)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        b2=Button(self, text="Blue",command=call_blue).grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=ALL)


        self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
        b3=Button(self, text="Green",command=call_green).grid(row=5, column=2, sticky=ALL)


        self.columnconfigure(3, weight=1)
        b4=Button(self, text="Black",command=call_black ).grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=ALL)

        self.columnconfigure(4, weight=1)
        b5=Button(self, text="Open",command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=5, column=4, sticky=ALL)
        #------------------------------

        f1 = Frame(self, bg="blue")
        f1.grid(row=0, column=0, rowspan=2,columnspan=2,  sticky=ALL)
        f1.bind("<Button-1>", handler)
        f1.focus()

        f2 = Frame(self, bg="green")
        f2.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=2,columnspan=2,  sticky=ALL)
        f2.bind("<Button-1>", handler)
        f2.focus()

        f3 = Frame(self, bg="red")
        f3.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=4, columnspan=4,  sticky=ALL)

        l=Label(f3, text="Enter File Path:").grid(row=1)

        e1 = Entry(f3)
        e1.grid(row=1,column=2)


root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should assign a `weight` to the column and row in which you place the text:

```
f3.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
f3.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)
```

This tells Tkinter that it should distribute any extra space to that row and column, which will make the cell grow upon resize.

You might want to add `sticky=ALL` to your `e1` then too, so it resizes with the text below it.